# Heroku deployment sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, sqlite

When im deploying on heroku i get

```
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
 !

 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

i want using it with [ClearDB MySQL Database](https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb)

chunk of my gemfile

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.10'
```

or its imposible to use sqlite on heroku?

Any suggestions?

thx

Comment: You already read this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3  (from your log)?

Answer (score 2):

i fixed it

add `gem 'mysql2'` instead of  `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.10'` and its working as i expected